# How to Show/Hide some elements based on value of a textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sale landing page. I added a text field for a promo code.
It is a simple promo code system. It gives always same discount for any promo code (the idea is to create custom promo code for each influencer).

I created 2 DIV for the prices and payment button.

There is the default DIV for the price without discount. It is shown by default when the page is loaded.

[image: default form without discount]

And there is the 2nd DIV which is displayed the discount and the new prices when visitor type the PROMOCODE.

[image: what suppose to show]

Everything works fine for 1 coupon. But I need to make it work for several different coupon codes. So I added the operator "OR", but it doesn't work anymore.

[image: error]

This is my code:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
        
     // Function to hide/show the table based on the values of inputs
    function toggleTable() {


    $('#hideThis').toggle($('#coupon').val() !== 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() !== 'PROMOGH2019');
    $('#hideThis3').toggle($('#coupon').val() !== 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() !== 'PROMOGH2019');
    $('#showThis').toggle($('#coupon').val() == 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() == 'PROMOGH2019');
    $('#showThis2').toggle($('#coupon').val() == 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() == 'PROMOGH2019');
    $('#showThis3').toggle($('#coupon').val() == 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() == 'PROMOGH2019');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Bind the keyup event on both the inputs, call the function on event
        $('#coupon').on('keyup', toggleTable).trigger('keyup');
    });
             
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<span >Vous avez un code PROMO?</span>
<input type="text" name="coupon" id="coupon" placeholder="Ex: PROMO2019">
</form>
            
<div id="showThis">
   <div>
      <b style="color:#000000;">Prix HT:<strike>594€</strike></b>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="hideThis">
   <div>
      <b>Prix HT:594€</b>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="showThis2">
   <div>
     <b>Remise  exceptionnelle de -50%</b><br><br>
     <b style="color:#36C503;">Prix final à payer: 297€</b>
   </div>
</div>
            
<div id="hideThis3">
  <div class="div_button">
     <a href="URL_594_euros" class="myButton"><span>&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Acheter Maintenant 594€</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="showThis3">
  <div class="div_button">
    <a href="URL_297_euros" class="myButton"><span>&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Acheter Maintenant 297€</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I searched everywhere here and on Google the same kind of issue, but I couldn't find any solution.

Can someone help me please to understand what is the issue with this operator or "||" create this issue?

Comment: You should check code validity in backend for security. I'm assuming you have a database where you would store all the codes? Consider having 20 different codes, do you want to edit your JS code every time one of them changes or is it easier to use SQL to check if inserted code is valid. Also remember that JS code is not hidden from users, anyone can read it using browser's devtools, so all the codes in your if check are visible with this approach.

Comment: Witty visitors could just look into your source code and see all the available codes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, i dont habe a coupon sustem with php. And I know that some visitors could see my coupon code. But i am launching this product, and this will be a temporal solution untill I invest in a new system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this lines

```
 $('#hideThis').toggle($('#coupon').val() !== 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() !== 'PROMOGH2019');
 $('#hideThis3').toggle($('#coupon').val() !== 'JDCM' || $('#coupon').val() !== 'PROMOGH2019');
```

To this:

```
 $('#hideThis').toggle($('#coupon').val() !== 'JDCM' && $('#coupon').val() !== 'PROMOGH2019');
 $('#hideThis3').toggle($('#coupon').val() !== 'JDCM' && $('#coupon').val() !== 'PROMOGH2019');
```

In your code when you write a coupon (like JDCM), it will always be different from the other coupon of the condition, so that the original price will never be hidden